# Displaying confirmation with file name after upload

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

He, I was trying to figure out how to display the file name and extension as the confirmation message after upload.

This is what I have right now

```
    <?php
// Check if a file has been uploaded
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    // Make sure the file was sent without errors
    if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) {
        // Connect to the database
        $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test_db');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
        }


        // Gather all required data
        $name = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        $mime = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']);
        $data = $dbLink->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));
        $size = intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']);

        // Create the SQL query
        $query = "
            INSERT INTO `file` (
                `name`, `mime`, `size`, `data`, `created`
            )
            VALUES (
                '{$name}', '{$mime}', {$size}, '{$data}', NOW()
            )";

        // Execute the query
        $result = $dbLink->query($query);

        // Check if it was successfull
        if($result) {
           echo "Your file has been uploaded";
        }
        else {
            echo 'Error! Failed to insert the file'
               . "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'An error accured while the file was being uploaded. '
           . 'Error code: '. intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']);
    }

    // Close the mysql connection
    $dbLink->close();
}
else {
    echo 'Error! A file was not sent!';
}

// Echo a link back to the main page
echo '<p>Click <a href="index.html">here</a> to go back</p>';
?>
```

Instead of echoing "your file has been uploaded," I would like it to list the name and extension of the file that was uploaded and then "was uploaded successfully" at the end.

Example: I upload contact.pdf. I was like it to display "contact.pdf was uploaded successfully"
I would like this to work for any file and extension. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You could just change the according `echo` string. Before outputting that overly optimistic message though, you might want to test if the database-stored *temporary* filename outlasts another page request.

Comment: How would i go about doing that? I'm still new to all of this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to get the name of the file out of the FILES variable:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

You may want to use some of the file methods to get the parts of the file name you want:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

Comment: i fixed my problem 
        if($result) {
           echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']). " was successfully uploaded.";
        }`